# « Relever une pêche » : de quel(s) sens du verbe relever s'agit-il ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, cinéma, guillemets

> Jusqu'en 1924,
>  les habitants de l'Île aux Coudres
>  tendaient
>   une pêche aux marsouins
>  sur le fleuve St-Laurent.
>
> À l'instigation des cinéastes,
>  les gens de l'île
>  ont “**relevé
>   la pêche**” en 1962
>  pour en perpétuer la mémoire
>
> [ Introduction du documentaire [*Pour la suite du monde*](https://www.onf.ca/film/pour_la_suite_du_monde/)
>   ([Brault](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michel_Brault)/[Perrault](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre_Perrault)), 1962, sur le site de l'ONF ; je souligne. ]

Le verbe [*relever*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/relever) a plusieurs sens, au propre et au figuré dont *remettre debout (une personne), à flot (un navire), prendre à terre, reprendre (une maille), reconstruire (une construction), remettre dans la situation où il se trouvait auparavant, donner plus de valeur, déterminer et noter la configuration, la disposition de quelque chose (topographie), accepter/répondre (à un défi)* (méli-mélo provenant du TLFi) ; ainsi que certains sens régionaux comme *reproduire le type de*, et *aller soigner une accouchée jusqu'à ses relevailles* ([GPCF](http://bibnum2.banq.qc.ca/bna/numtxt/179630.pdf)). On note que c'est entre [guillemets](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3391)...

En tenant compte de l'emploi des guillemets, de quel ou quels sens s'agit-il ici et pourquoi ?

Answer (score 1):

Je comprends cela comme une métaphore qui signifie en fait :

> Relever *le filet* de pêche

J'ai employé *filet* comme j'aurais pu employer tout autre instrument pouvant servir à pêcher. L'essentiel c'est que « Relever la pêche » c'est « récupérer le produit de la pêche », quel que soit le mode.

Comment: Est-ce possible svp d'élaborer davantage ? Je n'ai pas détaillé le procédé, mais la  « pêche » au marsouins ne se faisait pas avec un filet mais bien en construisant un « enclos » de [_harts_](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/hart) (pieux) plantés à intervalles dans l'eau. Le mammifère marin entre dans cet enclos à marée haute et reste pris quand la marée baisse, vu qu'il utilise, j'imagine, des ultrasons pour identifier les obstacles. Par ailleurs je n'aurais pas présenté un documentaire si on avait tué un tel mammifère, c'est une histoire qui finit bien...